# How to do a Python DataFrame Boolean Mask on nan values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe called 'vp' and in some of the rows, 'rev' is a positive float and in the others, 'rev' does not exist (NaN).

How to section this dataframe into its 2 components?  I tried this

```
vpbook = vp[vp['rev'] > 0]              # works 
vpnonbook = vp[~vp['rev'] > 0]          # does not work
```

The line that does not work yields:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'invert' not supported for the input types, and the inputs 
could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting 
rule ''safe''
```

How to do this?

Comment: vpnonbook = vp[!vp['rev'] > 0] , In R you can using ~ in python it is !

Comment: '>0' is not the correct Test for nan or valid float,  there is 'isnan' as the apptopriate function. However,  your error should only be caused by lacking parantheses. To invert a boolean array, ~ has to be applied on that array, not only on the first float array: 'vpnonbook = vp[~(vp['rev'] > 0)]' - EDIT: Oh my, and @Wen is additionally right, of course, please use '!'...

Comment: SpghttCd, you are right, if you 'answer' I will accept it

Comment: Using isnull and notnull to select

Comment: I tried using isnull function but it didn't like it in the context of a Boolean mask